# How to create a file in a directory where the name of such directory is specified in a command line argument in C

Tags: c

I've done:

```
 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen("../argv[2]/dummyfile", "w");
```

but it takes "argv[2]" literally. How do I make it not take it literally?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`sprintf`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm) to create the required file path string.

```
    int lenbuf = FILENAME_MAX;
    char filePath[lenbuf];
    
    int n = snprintf(filePath, lenbuf, "../%s/dummyfile", argv[2]);

    if(n > -1 && n < lenbuf){
      fp = fopen(filePath, "w");
    }else{
      printf("Error while creating path from input arguments");
      // handle the error here, user default or do exit/return
    }
```

Comment: `snprintf` with error checking would make this perfect.

Comment: Hey @Ry-, Thanks for the feedback, I included the error checks, does this looks good ? Please suggest if the error handling can also be done in a other way.

Comment: Yep, that’s good error handling for `sprintf`! But s**n**printf will avoid a potential buffer overflow.

Comment: Thanks, @Ry-, incorporated the suggestions.

Comment: Hey @DavidC.Rankin, Thanks for the suggestion, yes the code was not much readable earlier, I have incorporated your second suggestion, and it looks good now.

Comment: `n < sizeof(lenbuf)` should have been `n < lenbuf`.

Comment: Using just 32 characters for `filePath` only allows for `argv[2]` of up to 18 characters — which is uncomfortably small.  You should use a bigger buffer; I'd suggest 256 bytes as a start, and might use 1024 or even 4096.

Comment: Thanks @M.NejatAydin for the feedback, I fixed the error.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler for the feedback, Yes should have created a bigger array. Updated the answer with a bigger array.

Comment: The most correct value of the size of the buffer to hold the path is probably the standardized `FILENAME_MAX` (chapter 7.21.1 of the standard C17: "[...] which expands to an integer constant expression that is the size needed for an array of char large enough to hold the longest file name string that the implementation guarantees can be opened"

Comment: Thanks @thebusybee, your suggestion will ensure that the code will work for all the fileNames, I have updated my answer with your suggested changes.